# Finding path of file resource bundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have a jar that refers to a a properties file:

```
ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundle1");
```

How do I find where this bundle came from, as in its file path?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getLocale()) indicates that the call to getBundle(String) retrieves the bundle from the default location within the classloader.  This means that one of the .jar files currently loaded has this resource in it's base resource folder.

Reading a bit more, it doesn't seem like there's a way to extract the path programmatically.